# Phalcon choose version to install

Tags: php, phalcon

When I update my server, my phalcon version has passed to 4.0.0-alpha-1, and my project does not work. I have good version of PHP, and installed PSR extension.

I wanted use phalcon develop tools for create new project phalcon and compare, but it seems not compatible with new version of phalcon...

How install manually phalcon 3.4.2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with repository at this moment. To downgrade your library use this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.2-phalcon
sudo apt-get install php7.2-phalcon=3.4.*
sudo apt-mark hold php7.2-phalcon
```

Then restart your Apache/Nginx/PHP-FPM service.

Comment: this is happening again, and phalcon 4 is not compatible with phalcon 3.

Answer (score 3):

The versioning issue is fixed today. Now you can use the usual approach when installing or updating the Phalcon framework.

How the Phalcon Team will schedule framework releases in the future:

- `Stable` versions correspond to Phalcon release tags and should be used
  in production (eg. `v3.4.2`)
- `Mainline` versions correspond to Phalcon release tags which *are not stable*. Сan be used *with care* by experienced users (eg. `v4.0.0-alpha.1`)
- `Nightly` versions are built daily and *should not* be used in production

Installation/configuration details for each version and operating system can be found below:

### Configuration

**DEB packages**

```
# Stable releases
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

# Mainline releases
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/mainline/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

# Nightly releases
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/nightly/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

**RPM packages**

```
# Stable releases
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash

# Mainline releases
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/mainline/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash

# Nightly releases
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/nightly/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

**Programmatic way**

```
export BASE_URI="https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories"
export PRODUCT=phalcon
export BRANCH=mainline
export PACKAGE=rpm

curl -s "${BASE_URI}/${PRODUCT}/${BRANCH}/script.${PACKAGE}.sh" | sudo bash
```

### Installation

Select the required package from the list using the command as follows:

**DEB packages**

```
# Phalcon PHP framework
apt-cache search phalcon | grep "High performance PHP framework"

# Debug symbols for Phalcon
apt-cache search phalcon-dbgsym
```

**RPM packages**

```
# Phalcon PHP framework
yum search phalcon | grep "High performance PHP framework"

# Debug symbols for Phalcon
yum search phalcon | grep "Debug information for package"
```

### Download packages manually

- Packages for [stable version](https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable)
- Packages for [mainline version](https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/mainline)
- Packages for [nightly version](https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/nightly)